# MS Access 2000 Report needs to be PDF format with URL hyperlinks

Tags: ms-access, pdf, url

Working on an old MS Access 2000 database I didn't create. Has a working "projects report" which the client wants to send to prospects as a PDF document, replacing the currently-text-only project title with a title that is also a hyperlink linking to a web page (we can generate the URL programmatically).

Note: Access 2000 does not have a built-in "hyperlink" object for its reports as far as I know -- not sure if newer versions do or not.

Any ideas re: the best/quickest way to go about this? Development time/cost is a concern/constraint, but it's a long enough project list they'd rather not have to export the report to Word or something and manually create the URL links, exporting to PDF as a third step.

Comment: So far as I'm aware, you can only have a bare URL end up as clickable in a PDF generated from Office. You also have to be careful about the character spacing. I recently had to troubleshoot an unclickable URL for a client, printed to PDF from Word, and found that the expanded character spacing applied in Word ended up getting encoded in the PDF as actual spaces between the letters, so "http://MyURL.com" was coming out as "ht tp: // M yU RL . co m".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this for creating the PDF.

http://www.lebans.com/reporttopdf.htm

As for having a URL in the PDF...I don't think it can be done.  But I would wait for others to comment to be sure.

Seth

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It looks like David W. Fenton's comments above re: "bare URL only" is true as well. You can setup a URL datatype, but that's not really what I was after -- I needed the text to read as plain text, but end up clickable via hyperlink.

Fortunately, the client abandoned this idea altogether, for unrelated reasons. : )